# Bootstrap5 Dropdown collapses when clicking selecting child link

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I used a dropdown to create a menu.
The problem is that once the heading is expanded and a sublink is clicked- the menu collapses- when it is suppose to take me to a link. Im quote certain this has to do with the structure of the bs collapsing utility.

```
                    <li data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#verandering" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="verandering">
                        <a href="#">Verandering </a>
                        <ul class="overlay__inner collapse" id="verandering">
                            <li><a href="/sector">Sector</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/thema">Thema</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/cases">Cases</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jquery to prevent the dropdown from collapsing :)

```
 $('.overlay__inner').on('click', function() {
$(this).addClass("show");
$(this).removeClass("collapsing");
$(this).removeClass("collapse");
});
```